# What is the Importance of "Run continuous integration triggers for committed changes"

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, azure-devops

What is the importance of "**Run continuous integration triggers for committed changes**" option available on VSTS Build definition?

When I check - I see two builds happening for one check-in, and only one when unchecked, which I totally understand.

What I don't understand is - The release is being triggered from both the builds. I'm failing to understand the importance of this option. Any help?

**Edit 1:**
Inverted question can be "How can I stop the release trigger for Gated Builds?"

I want the release to continue only from CI builds.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is used for Continuous integration build, with many scenarios, you don’t want to trigger continuous integration build, but sometimes, you also want to trigger continuous integration build for additional validation (different build definition with different tasks).

To conclude, uncheck that option to prevent triggering the continuous integration build.

Comment: thanks for the reply @starian, can you please elaborate on "...additional validation (different build definition with different tasks)"? this is what I'm not getting. Why it is triggering the release pipeline then?

Comment: For Gated build, you may just want to verify whether the project can build or not to save the time, so maybe there is just the tasks related to build task. For continuous integration build, you may want to verify it is working fine, for example, the REST API can be access or not, the returned result is right or not and need to publish artifact. Anyway, it can be done in gated build too, just per to requirement.

Comment: Regarding release pipeline, it is just based on the release definition setting (Continuous deployment trigger) for specified artifact, not related to that setting.

Comment: thanks, I got the point that you might have Tests and other integration conditions which will be verified in CI Build. Is there anyway I can stop the trigger for CD(release) for Gated builds?

Comment: that's a second question I guess :-)

Comment: Generally, you don't need to publish artifact in Gated build to save time, so it won't trigger the release. If you publish artifact in Gated build and enable Continuous deployment trigger for this build artifact in release, you can't stop it.

Comment: thank you, so I guess I need to have two CI flow here - one will control the Gated builds having no "publish" step, and other will continue once the changes are checked-in from the Gated build. am I guessing right?

Comment: Yes, you can, just per to which way is better for your requirement.

Answer (score 5):

By default, CI builds are not run after the gated check-in process is complete and the changes are checked in.
However, if you do want CI builds to run after a gated check-in, select the Run CI triggers for committed changes check box. When you do this, the build process does not add ***NO_CI*** to the changeset description. As a result, CI builds that are affected by the check-in are run.

Reference:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/build/triggers?view=vsts#TFVCgatedcheck_in

Comment: thanks @Sheethal for reply, can you please excplain the difference between a Gated Check-in build vs CI Build here? thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, lgtm